# Unexpected EOF while parsing on a very simple class

Tags: python, python-3.x

No inputs, just some pseudo private fields and basic assignments, but it is still giving me the unexpected EOF while parsing error. The exception is given at line 28, when there are 24 lines of code.

```py
class Word:

    def _init_(self,text,size):
        self._text = text
        self._size = size

    def get_size(self):
        return self._size

    def set_size(self,size):
        self._size = size

    def set_text(self,text):
        self._text = text

    def get_text(self):
        return self._text
```

These are the 2 other classes that work closest with this one as requested.

```py
from word import Word

class WordCloud:
    def _init_(self, count, freq, stop_words):
        self._count = count
        self._freq = freq
        self._stop_words = stop_words
        self._max = freq.maximum 
        self._min = freq.minimum
        self._words = []

        def __createword__(self):
            keys = self._freq.keys()
            list(keys)
            values = self._freq.values()
            list(values)
            for i in (0,self._count,1):
                if keys[i] not in stop_word:
                    newWord = Word(keys[i], math.log(values[i]))
                    self._words.append(newWord)
                else:
                     i+= -1

    def save(self,filename):
        for i in self._words:
             firstnum = i.get_size()
             for j in self._words:
                 secondnum = j.get_size()
                 if(secondnum > firstnum)and(j>i):
                     self._words[i],self._words[j] = self._words[j],self._words[i]

        with open(filename,'w') as f:
             for word in self._words:
                f.write(word.get_text() + ':' + str(word.get_size()) +'\n')




class HtmlWordCloud(WordCloud):
    def _init_(self,count,freq,stop_words):
        WordCloud._init_(self, count, freq, stop_words)

    def save(self, filename):
        def size(self,size):
            maxSize = math.log(self._max)
            minSize= math.log(self._min)
            lowerBound = minSize
            for i in range(0,91,1):
                upperBound = minSize+((i+1)/91)*(maxSize-minSize)
                if(size==minSize):
                    return 10
                if(size>lowerBound) and (size<=upperBound):
                    return 10+i
                lowerBound = upperBound
        header = '''
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
'''

        f = open(filename,'w')
        f.write(header)
        itercount = 0
        for i in self._words:
            size = size(i.get_size())
            line ='''               <td><span style = "font-size:'+str(size)+'pt">'+i.get_text()+'</span></td>
'''
            f.write(line)
            itercount+=1
            if itercount is 5:
                newrow ='''
            </tr>
            <tr>
'''
                f.write(newrow)
                itercount = 0
        tail = '''
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>'''
        f.write(tail)
        f.close()
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: Clearly Python was expecting something more; you didn't *close* something and Python read all the way to the last line in your file (if the last few lines were empty). What you posted is not 24 lines however.

Comment: A few notes on this code: `_init_` is not the same thing as `__init__` (and, in particular, will not get called by `Word('spam', 3)`). There is no need for getters and setters like this, and in fact they're considered an anti-pattern. However, all that being said, there's no way the code you're showing us could be where the actual problem is. Without seeing the actual code, and the actual traceback instead of just a description of it, there's no way we can debug this.

Comment: Did you copy the code from somewhere? Maybe there are hidden and/or non ASCI characters lurking that are screwing up the parser.

Comment: This is a class I wrote on the side to turn a dictionary object i had created from another class into a list of these Word objects.I looked through all of my code, and everything is closed. I assume when you mention the _init_, i did do double underscores for the private method, but it didn't help. I could post the rest of the code, but that's close to 2k lines, so I'd rather not.

Comment: `def size(self,size)` and `size = size(i.get_size())` look destined to end in tears. `__createword__()` nested inside `_init_()` is a little mystifying.

Comment: Note: you can end `'''` only using `'''`. You code tries to end it with mere `'`. Try to use any editor that hightlights Python code to see string boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, the error is simple. EOF means python hit the end of the file while looking for something. You have a missing closing quote, brace or parenthesis somewhere. If python is telling you this, it is a fact.

Without seeing the actual code and error message we can only guess where.